# When should Square OAuth access tokens be renewed?

Tags: oauth, square, square-connect

We are attempting to auto-renew Square OAuth access tokens automatically (on a daily basis) to avoid service interruption. One thing we are confused on is when exactly access tokens can be renewed.

[The Square API OAuth overview page](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/basics/oauth/overview) mentions:

> Square OAuth access tokens expire after 30 days with a grace period of 15 days. Applications must manually renew expired access tokens within the 15 day grace period.

[The Oauth token details reference page](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/oauth#accesstokendetails) mentions:

> If you attempt to renew an unexpired token, the token's lifetime is not extended.

Does this mean that you can't extend a token's lifetime until it expires (within the 15 day grace period)?

If so, do expired access tokens still work within that 15 day grace period?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that wording is a bit confusing. In the docs we have:

> OAuth tokens cannot be renewed until they are at least 24 hours old.

When you renew an OAuth access token, you most likely will get a different access token, so it's technically not extending the token's lifetime, because it's actually making a new token with a new expiration date.